# Proving A has non-zero Eigenvector with the unit sphere doubt

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Theorem: Let $A$ be a real symmetric $n\times n$ matrix. Let $f(X)=\langle AX,X\rangle$
>
> for $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $v$ be on the unit sphere, such that $f(v)\geqslant f(X)$ for all $X$ on this sphere. Then $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

Proof. Let $w$ be a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is perpendicular to $v$. It is easily shown that there exists a differentiable curve

$C:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}^n$

lying on the sphere, defined on an open interval containing $0$, such that $C(0)=v$ and such that the tangent vector $C$ at $0$ is $w$, namely $C´(0)=w$.
[For instance, the curve $C(t)=(\cos t)v+(\sin t)w$ is such a curve.] Since $f(v)=f(C(0))$ is a maximum for $f$ on $S$, it is a maximum for $f(C)$ on the interval $(a,b)$, and hence $(f(C))´(0)=0$. But by using the rule for differentiating a product,´

$(f(C))´(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\langle AC(t),C(t)\rangle=2\langle AC(t),C´(t)\rangle$.

Hence $0=f(C)´(0)=2\langle AC(0),C´(0)\rangle=2\langle Av,w\rangle$.

Hence $Av$ is perpendicular to every vector $w$ which is perpendicular to $v$. and it follows that $Av$ lies in the space generated by $v$, in other words, there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $Av=\lambda v$. This proves our theorem. ***Linear Algebra,Serge Lang***

**Questions:**

**1)** What does $C:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ mean? The author says that $C(0)=v$. Is C the sphere equation?

**2)** How is $C(t)=(\cos t)v+(\sin t)w$ a curve on the sphere? I understand $(\cos t,\sin t,0)$ to be a curve on the unit sphere once $\cos^2 t+\sin^2(t)+0=1$ if consider $n=3$ ($\mathbb{R}^3$).But since $C(t)=(\cos t)v+(\sin t)w$ has the vectors $v$ and $w$ multiplying I do not see how this is on the unit sphere.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The notation $f: X \to Y$ means that the function $f$ maps the set $X$ to the set $Y$.

Comment: Compute $\|C(t)\|$ and you will see why $C(t)$ is on the sphere.

Comment: @Gribouillis                      $\|C(t)\|=\sqrt{\langle C(t),C(t)\rangle}=\sqrt{\cos^2 tv^2+sin^2 t}=\sqrt{v^2+1}$, but I guess when the author says $v$ is on the sphere the author is not referring it is inside the unit sphere right? Otherwise $||v||=1$.

Comment: $v$ is on the sphere does mean that $\|v\|=1$. Your result $\sqrt{v^2+1}$ is false.

Comment: @Gribouillis I was visualizing $v$ tangent to the sphere. Thanks!